# fig throws exception after installation

Tags: python, archlinux, fig

I installed `fig` on `Arch Linux` using the following command `sudo pip install -U fig`. After the installation was completed, I've tried to run `fig --version` but this gave me following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fig", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2880, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 432, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 741, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 626, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
  pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: fig==1.0.1
```

As it can be seen in the errors, I use `python2`. I also tried using `python3`, but I've got the same error.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed `fig` when `python3` with set as default. After setting `python2` as default, I've reinstalled `fig` and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try upgrading pip with easy_install:

```
easy_install --upgrade pip
```

Then try reinstalling fig.